# How to rewrite [es:di] to att syntax

Tags: assembly, x86-16, att, addressing-mode, memory-segmentation

This is a short question but I did not manage to find the answer online.

How do you rewrite `mov [es:di], dl` into AT&T syntax?

I use it to write a pixel to the screen in real mode.

Comment: `mov %dl,%es:(%di)`

Comment: You can always assemble something with nasm and disassemble it with `objdump -drwC` to get the AT&T disassembly of the machine code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch when i do that, i get the error: '%es:(%di)' is not a valid base/index expression

Comment: The only reason that would be an invalid expression is if you are generating this as 64-bit code. Using a 16-bit register in a memory operand in 64-bit code is not supported.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks, i managed to fix the error

Answer (score 2):

`mov %dl, %es:(%di)`:

In the AT&T Syntax, memory is referenced in the following [way](https://csiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Essdavis/50/att-syntax.htm):

`segment-override:signed-offset(base,index,scale)`

parts of which can be omitted depending on the address you want.

`%es:100(%eax,%ebx,2)`

A [corresponding](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/as/i386_002dMemory.html#index-i386-memory-references-888) Intel syntax indirect memory reference:

`segment-override:[base + index*scale + signed-offset]`

`es:[eax + ebx*2 + 100]`

Comment: For NASM the segment override goes either inside the brackets (`[es:di]` like in the question) or before the instruction (`es lodsb`).